# How to save value checked in asp.net mvc and dropdownlist using c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, bootstrap-4

I need some help, i have list of countries and checkbox on Razor. I need to find a way to save these to my table from the database. Here is my logic to do this below; I want to save them for both, meaning for countrylist, if selected for that country it must store DB and same with checkbox. Got stuck, please help mates according below. If there is a controller must add, then i will use it but dont know how.

Controller

```
//POST /Home/DietaryListOptions
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DietOptions(DietViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    return View("Success");
}
```

Load the list of countries in the world

```
private List<RegistrationTrainingForm> LoadData()
{
    List<RegistrationTrainingForm> lst = new List<RegistrationTrainingForm>();

    try
    {
        string line = string.Empty;
        string srcFilePath = "Content/files/country_list.txt";
        var rootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
        var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, srcFilePath);
        string filePath = new Uri(fullPath).LocalPath;
        StreamReader src = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

        // while to read the file
        while ((line = src.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            RegistrationTrainingForm infoLst = new RegistrationTrainingForm();
            string[] info = line.Split(',');

            //Setting
            infoLst.Country_Id = Convert.ToInt32(info[0].ToString());
            infoLst.Country_Name = info[1].ToString();

            lst.Add(infoLst);
        }
        src.Dispose();
        src.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex);
    }
    return lst;
}
```

List for countries

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCountryList()
{
    SelectList listcn = null;
    try
    {
        var list = this.LoadData().Select(p => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = p.Country_Id.ToString(),
            Text = p.Country_Name
        });
        listcn = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return listcn;
}
```

ViewModels

```
public class DietViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "None")]

    [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true")]
    public bool None { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vegetarian")]

    [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true")]

    public bool Vegetarian { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vegan")]

    [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true")]
    public bool Vegan { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Halaal")]

    [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true")]
    public bool Halaal { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Other")]

    [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true")]
    public bool Other { get; set; }
}

public class DropDownViewModel
{
    public int Country_Id { get; set; }

    public string Country_Name { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<div class="form-check">
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.Vegetarian, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
  <label class="form-check-label" for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.DietMain.Vegetarian)">Vegetarian</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.Vegan, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
  <label class="form-check-label" for="@Html.IdFor(m=>m.DietMain.Vegan)">Vegan</label>
</div>
```

Comment: want you pass value each checkbox is checked to controller then save your db ?

Comment: @Zanyar yes i want logic around that

Answer (score 0):

> Already only checkbox value pass when checked

if your value not `true or false` normally pass each checkbox when checked

### Set value checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="yourInputName" name="yourInputName" value="yourvalue" />
```

### Get value in controller

```
public ActionResult DietOptions(string yourInputName) // your datatype
```

**you can get value by `Request.Form`**

```
var form = Request.Form;
var value = form["yourInputName"]; // can you cast for your dataType
```

> But if your datatype **Bool** must set default value because if not check pass null can pass **False**

**You can fixed your issue buy using some way**

You can pass value by normal parameter

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Vegetarian " name="Vegetarian " value="true" /> // if check ed pass true else pass null, you can change true to false when checked
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult DietOptions(bool Vegetarian = false) // if checked true else false
```

**Or can you set default value in your Entity **

```
public class DietViewModel
{
     ....
     [Display(Name = "Vegetarian")]
     [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true")]
     public bool Vegetarian { get; set; } = false;
     ....

}
```

## Anther way can you use [Partial Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) for set default value and not effect original class